# How can I solve this differential equation through Laplace transforms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y''-2y'+2y=0$ where $y(0)=0,~~y'(0)=1$. So I started solving this by doing the following

$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)-2sY(s)-y(0)+2Y(s) = 0 \\
(s^2-2s+2)Y(s)-1=0 \implies Y(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-2s+2} = \frac{1}{(s-1)^2+1}$$

I am stuck on how to find the Laplace inversion given this transform. According to notes from class, the answer should be $y(t)=e^t\sin t$ but I don't see how to come to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$$\mathcal{L}\{y''-2y'+2y=0\} = (s^2 y(s) - sy(0)-y'(0)) -2 (sy(s) - y(0)) +2 y(s) = 0$$

with: $y(0)=0,~~y'(0)=1$

Substitute for the IC's, solve for $y(s)$ and then find the inverse Laplace Transform.

We get:

$$y(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2-2s+2}$$

Now, you just need to take $\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{y(s)\} = y(t)$.

We can write this as (complete the square):

$$y(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2-2s+2} = \dfrac{b}{(s-a)^2 + b^2} = \dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2 + 1^2}$$

From the [*Table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), item $19.$,  we have:

$$\mathcal{L^{-1}} \left(\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2 + 1^2}\right) = e^t \sin t$$

Comment: Well, that is what I am trouble finding. I did everything up to what you said, but don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: I did that as well above, but do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Ok, that's what I suspected the answer to be but just didn't have a way to verify. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you need the Laplace transformation table and try to match a certain format